# Can you save each factor of a polynomial?

Tags: factorization

I have a question I'm factoring a polynomial in Mathematica. After having the polynomial factored, I want to manipulate each factor. So my question is if there is anyway I can save each factor in a list (like we do with CoefficientList).

For example, having this:

```
1. (3.56524*10^7 + 1070.28 s + 1. s^2) (7.73698*10^6 + 2583.89 s + 1. s^2)
```

I want to be able to manipulate there factors and their coefficients.
Is that possible?

Comment: You can change the `Head` to `List` to get a list of factors. `Apply[List, (3.56524*10^7 + 1070.28 s + 1. s^2) (7.73698*10^6 +2583.89 s + 1. s^2)]`

Comment: Maybe `FactorList` would be useful in this situation.

Comment: Just to complete the answers of @Natas and @ Daniel Lichtblau, you might want to address the factors manually one by one. This is the expression: `expr=1.*(a s+1)*(b*s-2)` Then `expr[[1]]` returns 1, `expr[[2]]` returns `1 + a s` and `expr[[3]]` yields `-2 + b s`.